# Assigning SQL Query Result to a Variable

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have the following SQL query.
The SQL query returns a single value so it's working.

How can fix this situation?
Thank you.

Here, I want to assign the INTEGER value that I found using the CAST function to the NEWMATERIAL by incrementing it by one.

```
OBJECT:

INTEGER DGR;

SELECT CAST(RIGHT(MATERIAL,4)AS INTEGER) FROM IASMATMOP WHERE MATERIAL LIKE 'EST-00%' ORDER BY MATERIAL DESC LIMIT 1;

NEWMATERIAL = DGR+1;
```

How can fix this situation?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The given SQL code starts by declaring an INTEGER variable called DGR. It proceeds to execute an SQL query that extracts the last 4 digits from the MATERIAL column within the IASMATMOP table, converting these digits to an INTEGER, and storing this result in the DGR variable. Afterward, it performs a simple increment of the DGR variable by one. Finally, the code assigns the updated value of DGR to a variable named NEWMATERIAL. Essentially, this code accomplishes the retrieval, incrementation, and assignment of a value obtained from a database query, serving the purpose of making the incremented value available for further use.

```sql
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateNewMaterial()
BEGIN
  DECLARE DGR INT;

  SELECT CAST(RIGHT(MATERIAL, 4) AS SIGNED) INTO DGR
  FROM IASMATMOP
  WHERE MATERIAL LIKE 'EST-00%'
  ORDER BY MATERIAL DESC
  LIMIT 1;

  SET DGR = DGR + 1;

  UPDATE YourTable SET NEWMATERIAL = DGR; -- Replace YourTable with the actual table name
END //

DELIMITER ;

CALL UpdateNewMaterial();
```

Comment: DECLARE, SET var and SET INTO var are not suitable for MariaDB functions; hence, the above query does not work.

Comment: Oops my bad, this query should now work as expected. Answer is now edited.